# display 2 separate custom view in 1 activity android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view

i have 2 separate custom view in 1 activity. 
i have 2 question:

1- how can i do this(put 2 view side by side)?

2- and how can i put second view in second half of the display it means how to make view to consider (width/2,0) instead of (0,0) to start ??
note: the height of my views is the height of display and width of my views is width/2 of display's width.

i set the onMeasure() method like this

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int measuredWidth = widthMeasureSpec/2;
    int measuredHeight = heightMeasureSpec;
    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth,measuredHeight );
}
```

[image: display]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding both views inside a `LinearLayout` horizontal oriented, both with `weight=1`. It would look something like.-

```
<LinearLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <YourCustomView1
        android:width="wrap_content"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1" />

    <YourCustomView2
        android:width="wrap_content"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```